# How can I boot up an old HDD inside another OS?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ata

I found an **old** HDD while cleaning out the attic and was wondering if it was possible to see what it contains.

The drive is a pATA device manufactured in 2002, so I've had to buy a sATA to pATA adapter. I'm still waiting for the Molex and IDE cables to arrive, so I don't know if it even works.

That being said: is it possible to boot it up inside Linux sort of like a VM? I know I can (probably) browse it from inside the OS, but I'd prefer the first option.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd do it *exactly like* a VM. I'd set up KVM and set the he'd as the storage device.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the drive mounted, you can run something like Disk2VHD to turn the drive into a virtual hard drive (`.VHD` file). You can then mount that in something like VirtualBox, and boot into it from a host OS.

Comment: Perfect! I'll try this and come back and mark it as solved if it works.

Comment: Alternatively, VirtualBox can mount a harddisk directly as device. You need to create a vmdk file using command prompt that links to the drive and the drive must be offline. After that, you can boot directly in the VM as if it was a standalone computer. This way, you don't suffer if the image failed. https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm/#:~:text=To%20do%20so,%20open%20the,when%20creating%20the%20VMDK%20file.

Comment: @LPChip sounds like another answer. I didn't know you could do that (y).

Comment: Technically it is, but don't have time to write one now.